# What is the pointwise, absolute and uniform convergence of the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

To study the convergence properties of the series of functions:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$$
We begin with point convergence. For any fixed value of $x$, we need to check whether the sequence of functions converges. Let us denote by
$$f_n(x) = \left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$$
The domain of the arcosine function is $[-1, 1]$, so it must be $-1\leq \frac{2x^2-1}{x} \leq 1 \iff -1\leq x\leq-\frac 12 \vee \frac 12\leq x\leq 1$ that is, the series converges punctually, $\forall n\in\Bbb N$, in this interval.

To test absolute convergence, we consider the absolute value of the given series:
$$\left|\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n\right| =\left|\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right| ^n\leq \left(\frac{\pi}2\right)^n, \quad \forall n\in\Bbb N$$
But the series $\sum\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)^n$ is divergent and the our series not converges absolutely always for all $x\in[-1, -\frac 12]\cup [\frac 12,1]$. Hence I can not apply the $M-$Weierstrass criterion, i.e. I can not found a sequence $M_n$ with

$$|f_n(x)|\leq M_n.$$

Is it correct or I have found a wrong solution? I can not able to found the absolute and uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum f_n(x)\hbox{ convergent }\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 0\implies
$$
$$|f_n(x)| < 1\hbox{ for $n$ large enough}\iff$$
$$
\left|\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right| < 1\iff\left|\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right| < \sin(1).
$$
And you **also** need $-1\le\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\le 1$, but as $\sin(1) < 1$, every $x$ s.t. $\left|\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right| < \sin(1)$ is in the domain of $f_n$ (what is this set?).

Now, for **each** $x$:
$$
\left|\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right| < \sin(1)\implies
\left|\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right| < 1\implies
$$
$$
\sum f_n(x)\hbox{ absolutely convergent (why?).}
$$
For the M-Weierstrass criterion you need a bit more than $\left|\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right| < 1$ for all $x$ in some set...

Comment: I have understood you but if I take $M_n=1$ the sum is divergent. Please can you extend your answer continuing my steps, please?

Comment: I am very confuse. Please can you solve the final part? I am not able :-/